# Importing numba crashes with core dump

Tags: python, numba

I have recently performed various software updates as suggested by the "Software Center" on my Ubuntu machine (`Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS`).
Now, when I try to import `numba` (`numba==0.51.2`) via

```
python3 -c 'import numba'
```

I get the following error

> double free or corruption (top) Aborted (core dumped)

The same happens when I create a new conda environment with a fresh `numba` install.

I have looked at the core dump via

```
gdb -c core
```

with

```
thread apply all bt full
```

but I only get memory address information. I use python 3.6.9 on my machine, but I have also tried 3.8 in a new conda environment, where I get the same error.

I suspect that the software update is the reason for the error described above. But I might be mistaken and something else goes on here.

Is there any other way to get more info on where python crashes? I really don't want to go through the updated libraries one by one and roll them back to find the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least I have now found the library that causes this error.
What I did were the following steps:

1. put `import numba` into a file, e.g. `importNumba.py`
2. locate `python3.X-gdb.py` via `locate --regex python3.*-gdb.py`. In my case it is in `/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin/python3.6-gdb.py`
3. run python in debug mode via `gdb python3` - the gdb console opens
4. execute `source /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin/python3.6-gdb.py` in the gdb console - this will load the python extensions into gdb
5. execute `run importNumba.py` in the gdb console - this will produce above error
6. execute `py-bt` in the gdb console

This gives

```
Traceback (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/llvmlite/binding/ffi.py", line 113, in __call__
    return self._cfn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/llvmlite/binding/dylib.py", line 29, in load_library_permanently
    _encode_string(filename), outerr):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/__init__.py", line 151, in _try_enable_svml
    llvmlite.binding.load_library_permanently("libsvml.so")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/__init__.py", line 201, in <module>
    config.USING_SVML = _try_enable_svml()
  <built-in method exec of module object at remote 0x7ffff7fb7638>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "importNumba.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numba
```

So it seems something is wrong with `libsvml.so`.
I found out that `numba` allows to disable SVML via
setting the environment flag `NUMBA_DISABLE_INTEL_SVML` to something other than 0, see https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/envvars.html

Changing `importNumba.py` to

```
import os
# note that this must be executed before 'import numba'
os.environ['NUMBA_DISABLE_INTEL_SVML'] = '1'
import numba
```

and running it via `python3 importNumba.py` now works without error.

These were a few useful resources that I used:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/EasierPythonDebugging#New_gdb_commands
https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb

Comment: This `locate --regex python3.*-gdb.py` returns nothing. Could you help me with that? Thank you

Comment: You probably don't have python-dbg installed. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb for details on how to install it.